# Blackmagic RAW get Thumbnail in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, blackmagic

Is there any known Plug In or similair which can show BRAW Thumbnails in Windows Explorer? Or does anyone know how one could write such an Plug In?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a thumbnail provider available from here https://github.com/tom-gangemi/braw-thumbnail-provider/releases/tag/v1.0.

All you need to do is extract to your desired install location and run register.cmd.

Comment: Nice! Thank you and thank you for making it Open Source :)